# Context for this discrete Cauchy integral formula

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials, fourier-analysis

**Notation:** I will use the following conventions for discrete Fourier transforms (DFT) and discrete time Fourier transforms (DTFT):
$$\mathcal{D}_N[x_j](k) := \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} e^{-2\pi i j k} x_j$$
$$\mathcal{D}^{-1}_N[y_k](j) := \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} e^{2\pi i j k} y_k$$
$$\mathcal{F}[x_j](k) := \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty  e^{-2\pi i j k} x_j$$
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}[y(k)](j) := \int_0^1  e^{2\pi i j k} y(k)$$
Additionally, $\Omega_N$ will denote the set of $N^{th}$ roots of unity.

---

Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $N$ with coefficients $c_j$, $j=0,1,\dots,N$.  Consider the list of all coefficients as a vector $c$.  By taking a DFT of $c$ you can show that $$c_j = \mathcal{D}_N^{-1}\left[f\left(e^{-2\pi i k/N}\right)\right](j)\tag{1}$$  And analogously with a DTFT $$c_j = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[f\left(e^{-2\pi i k}\right)\right](j)\tag{2}$$

Actually the latter formula works perfectly well for analytic functions $f$, where $c$ is the the vector of Taylor coefficients, or with meromorphic functions and $c$ the Laurant coefficients.

I realized recently that this is basically just Cauchy's integral formula with a change of variables.  To see this, expand out the inverse DTFT:
$$\begin{align*}
c_j & = \int_0^1 e^{2\pi i k j} f(e^{-2\pi i k}) dk \\
& = \oint_{S^1} z^{-j} f(z) \frac{dz}{2\pi i z} \\
& = \frac{1}{j!} \frac{d^j f(0)}{dz^j}
\end{align*}$$
Where the last line is from Cauchy's formula.

So far this is all familiar.  However, from this perspective we see that eq. (1) can also be interpreted as a "discrete" version of Cauchy's integral formula, valid only for polynomials.  Rewriting it slightly, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{j!}\frac{d^j f(0)}{dz^j} = c_j & = \frac{1}{N} \sum_k e^{2\pi i j k} f(e^{-2\pi i k/N})\\
& = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{z\in \Omega_N} z^{-j} f(z) \tag{3}\\
\end{align*}$$

This circle of ideas seems like it would be useful for e.g. efficiently determining coefficients of a "black box" polynomial that you can only evaluate.  Or more generally any situation where you would want to use Cauchy's formula with a polynomial, this might be a convenient alternative.  However, I've never seen any of this before in textbooks or other literature.

**Question:** What, if anything, are eqs. (1) and (3) useful for?  Citations to literature welcome.

---

As I wrote this, I remembered vaguely something about "z-transforms".  After looking this up, it seems very closely related, though not quite identical.  I still haven't found anything exactly like eqs. (1) or (3).

Comment: isn't this a well-known connection? see [Taylor and Fourier series are the same](http://dev.ipol.im/~coco/website/taylorfourier.html)

Comment: I might be wrong, but my understanding was that one of the basic applications of the Fast Fourier transform (which is just an algorithm to do DFT fast on a computer) is precisely to make use of (1) in settings where evaluation of a polynomial function is easy, but you want to compute things related to the coefficients. 

The standard example is probably integer arithmetic on computers -- look up the basic fast integer multiplication algorithms a la Schönhage-Strassen.

Comment: this MO posting addresses a similar correspondence: https://mathoverflow.net/a/350028/11260